# Scrapy / extracting data across multiple HTML tags

Tags: xpath, scrapy

newbie to Scrapy, but catching up fast.  One thing I can't figure out, though, despite Googling and Copiloting, so I appreciate your patience :)  I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<p>
   "The "
   <strong class="meep">cat</strong>
   " sat "
   <a href="whatever1" title="whatever2">on</a>
   " the mat."
</p>
```

I went to the parent `div` of the `p`, and executed:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="whatever3"]/p[2]/text()').extract()
```

...but it outputs ['The ', 'sat', ' the mat.']

How can I add to the code to get "The cat sat on the mat."?  I also tried `following-sibling` syntax, but just couldn't get it to work.  I also tried using `join` but couldn't get that to work, here, either...

Appreciate thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mimic all text nodes value, simply you can use //text()

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="whatever3"]/p[2]//text()').extract()
```

**join method will textract strings into a single string separated by spaces.**

```
  ' '.join(response.xpath('//div[@class="whatever3"]/p[2]
    //text()').extract())
```

Comment: That gets me closer, for sure - thanks.  But it still returns an array of values - is it possible to join them into a single string?

Comment: You can easily do that in Python, no need to write a single XPath that does everything.